# MFC Custom tick marks are erased on slider move

Tags: mfc

I am drawing the Custom slider control. But my tic marks are getting erased on moving the thumb. I draw the ticks in ITEMPREPAINT as below:

```
if( lpcd->dwDrawStage == CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT )
    {
 if(lpcd->dwItemSpec == TBCD_TICS)
         {
             CDC *pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpcd->hdc);
            INT nMin=0,nMax=0,range;
            GetRange(nMin,nMax);
            range = nMax - nMin;

            INT num_tics = 4;
            INT frequency = range/num_tics;

            CRect channelRect, thumbRect;
            GetChannelRect(&channelRect);
            GetThumbRect(&thumbRect);
            INT width,pos=channelRect.left;

            /*pDC->MoveTo(pos,channelRect.bottom);
            pDC->LineTo(pos,channelRect.bottom+10);*/

            for (INT tic=0; tic<num_tics; tic++)
            {
                width = channelRect.right - channelRect.left;
                pos +=  width/num_tics;


                pDC->MoveTo(pos,channelRect.bottom);
                pDC->LineTo(pos,channelRect.bottom+10);
            }

           *pResult = CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
            return;
         }
}
```

Comment: I've never tried to draw tick marks in a slider, but, I would try rendering them during CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT.

Comment: Hi, If I remove the same implementation and do the same under CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT then i am not able to see the TICS on application start up. On click of the application from the below task bar, the tics are getting appeared because of the post paint. And if i am keeping the same implementaion under both pre paint and post paint section, the same rendering issue i am facing.